# How to take an element and break it up across multiple versions of the same list?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu

If I have this list:

```
a = ["1","2","t","fthdf","u"]
```

and I want to create 4 new list, with the same elements except for that in the third index which I want to basically splice up like so:

```
a = ["1","2","t","f","u"]
b = ["1","2","t","t","u"]
c = ["1","2","t","h","u"]
d = ["1","2","t","d","u"]
e = ["1","2","t","f","u"]
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Thank you very much for all your answers.

Comment: Any ideas? Have you tried writing any code for it?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: No, it's not like that, it's just that i have a hard time with list comprehension, i never know when i have to use it, the problem in the question is the root in a error that i was trying solve in code that i am developing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple list comprehension like

```
lists = [a[:3] + [elem] + a[4:] for elem in a[3]]

# [['1', '2', 't', 'f', 'u'],
#  ['1', '2', 't', 't', 'u'],
#  ['1', '2', 't', 'h', 'u'],
#  ['1', '2', 't', 'd', 'u'],
#  ['1', '2', 't', 'f', 'u']]
```

Comment: You can use destructuring assignment to get the output in separate variables as the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a list of strings which are iterable, you can use [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which returns *Cartesian product of input iterables*, notice here `*` to unpack the original list to pass them as individual parameters to `product`(this assumes all strings other than the ones you want to expand having only one character):

```
from itertools import product
list(product(*a))

#[('1', '2', 't', 'f', 'u'),
# ('1', '2', 't', 't', 'u'),
# ('1', '2', 't', 'h', 'u'),
# ('1', '2', 't', 'd', 'u'),
# ('1', '2', 't', 'f', 'u')]
```

Comment: You really should explain what all this does

Comment: @SterlingArcher It treats each item of `a` as a set, and determines the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of those sets. The item `fthdf` is treated as a set with 5 elements.

Comment: It only works if all list items except for `a[3]` are one one letter strings. This is nothing that the OP explicitly stated.